# Ruby Sequel STI model_map or key_map issue with DB queries

Tags: ruby, postgresql, module, sequel, single-table-inheritance

I have a module with a 'parent' class, *Trait*, and its 'children' inherited classes, *Text* and *Image*, using the Ruby Sequel gem with Postgresql within a module, *Tank*.

```
module Tank; end

module Tank
  class Trait < Sequel::Model
    plugin :single_table_inheritance, :type
  end
end

module Tank
  class Image < Trait; end
end

module Tank
  class Text < Trait; end
end
```

While within a console, I attempt to call #destroy on a trait. This results in an error because Sequel attempts to find a *Trait* with #type *Tank::Text* as shown below.

```
> Trait[439555].destroy
Sequel::NoExistingObject: Attempt to delete object did not result in
a single row modification (Rows Deleted: 0, SQL: DELETE FROM "traits" 
WHERE (("traits"."type" IN ('Tank::Text')) AND ("id" = 439555)))
```

I have tried using some of the advanced options; #model_map, #key_map, and #key_chooser as seen in the Sequel documentation: http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/classes/Sequel/Plugins/SingleTableInheritance.html.

Admittedly I am not so familiar with lambdas and procs, but this was my attempt:

```
module HoldingTank
  class Trait < Sequel::Model
    plugin :single_table_inheritance, :type,
    model_map: { 'Text'=>:Text, 'Image'=>:Image }
  end
end
```

and I tried adding the following when that did not work:

```
key_chooser: lambda {|i| i.model.sti_key_map[i.model.to_s.split('::').last].first}
```

with both tries having similar results to the following, where now it is searching for rows where 1 = 0 (obviously something went wrong):

```
> Trait[439555].destroy
Sequel::NoExistingObject: Attempt to delete object did not result in
a single row modification (Rows Deleted: 0, SQL: DELETE FROM "traits"
WHERE ((1 = 0) AND ("id" = 439555)))
```

For what it's worth, the *Trait* class already existed as entirely *Text* entries before I added STI. I updated all the current *Trait* instances to have #type = 'Text' which I have confirmed in the console. I also get these results and I don't know if they are to be expected or not as I am new to Sequel and STI:

```
> Text.count
=> 0
> Trait.where(type: 'Text').count
=> 931589
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.